# export matlab output to an excel file with location specified for a range of data

Tags: matlab, export, excel-2010

I want to export matlab output to an excel file starting from G2 column and for this the code i had written is exporting the data correctly but not to the desired location .It is printing in 21st number of rows rather than 2nd.
the code is

```
ResultFile = xlsread('filename');
 sz= size(ResultFile,1); 
b= num2str(sz+1);
 location = strcat('G2',b); 
fprintf('value in location is %g\n',location); 
xlswrite('filename',fnlarray,'Sheet1',location);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the command

```
xlswrite(filename,A,sheet,xlRange)
```

you can either specify `xlRange` as a string defining the corners of the desired output region, or (provided that you have specified the sheet) only give the coordinates of the upper-left cell. If you want to write an array to a region "below and to the right of G2", this should be enough:

```
location = 'G2';
```

Concatenating 'G2' with the number of rows of the excel file + 1 does not really seem to make sense to me right now.